# Simple CMS functionality like wordpress

Tags: java, php, wordpress, servlets, content-management-system

I need to develop simple CMS functionality, it supports multiple pages with static HTML ( with WYSIWYG  editor)

To keep it simple, I can save the content in DB and give an ID to the page and permalink.
For every request, take the permalink ( from URL) and serve the content read from the DB.

While this is not efficient, I can think of following approach, 
In the start-up and while editing, load the content and push it to the CDN server with permalink path. But, it increases the development efforts.

I have following questions based on above

1) Is it good practice to save the HTML content in DB, if not what are the alternatives ?

2) How does the Wordpress does this, So I can take design clues ?

3) Is there any very simple CMS product that I can customize, I cannot use wordpress because it has too many features, It would be better to develop the CMS rather than maintain the wordpress huge code base ?

Answer (score 1):

Saving HTML in DB is perfectly fine and AFAIK WordPress does it that way.

If you would do it by yourself you can provide some cache in files (e.g. for content visible on main page).

Anyway I would prefer WordPress, since it has e.g. anti-spam filters, sitemap generations and so on. And you have all updates for free, what is really important.

Comment: Yes, Wordpress does that way.
I just checked the MySQL wordpress DB, and I see the content in DB tables.

But, All those features are not required, and CMS will be used only by the admin. Not even comments for anti-spam.

Comment: @coder000001 why not wordpress ?? something around 5 MB is manageable i guess ??

Comment: Wordpress has huge codebase, for my requirement I need to modify it, hence it is a maintenance job would be too much.

Comment: @coder000001 if you are looking for future enhancements ..even if you go with some basic CMS this time..still u need to modify it later..what is the need of reinventing the wheel ?? .. worpdress DB structure is very well normalized so u can go with it

Comment: @swapnesh I really appreciate your response. But, the CMS tool also needs to be really simple and specific to the requirement, I am not sure if we can avoid confusing the user will all those options in the wordpress.

Comment: I´m pretty sure you´re reinventing the wheel..... You have to concern caching, WYSIWYG-editing, templating, image-upload, conditional HTTP-anwering, image-resizing and so on.

Comment: @clkj Thanks, I am searching for simple alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

As seen, saving HTML in the DB works. But definitely not the neatest approach for saving an entire page/template.

You should check out [CouchCMS](http://www.couchcms.com/). The developers made use of @stacker's approach. They introduced custom tags which can be used to declare variables within templates and then the content of the variables are automatically detected and can be saved in the database using the CMS.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, If the user is inputting static HTML through WYSIWYH. Sorry, I don't understand how the custom tags and templating engines comes into the scope.

Comment: Alright.

When you save HTML in the DB, you're most likely saving the content and layout in the DB.

An aspect of CouchCMS (Variables),
When building your template (in file) you can declare variables using the syntax `<cms:set my_message='Hello World' />` (In this case, the default content becomes "Hello World").

To display content, one uses `<cms:show my_message />` to display the content wherever in the file.

When page appears in CMS, WYSIWYG fields will be made available for `my_message` to update the content.

Point is, you're only saving content and not the entire layout.